# How to use sqlplus command to get output from sql developer to a file in windows

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I need to query a result from Sql developer to a file in windows.. Also I should not mention the username and password  of sql developer directly in the code to make it secure. How can I achieve it?

Comment: and the series of down votes are around the corner. They probably going to come and get this too.

Comment: You want to query a result ? "I need to query a result from Sql developer to a file in windows"..

Comment: You can't "query a result from SQL Developer". SQL Developer is a SQL client tool just like SQL\*Plus. SQL Developer also doesn't store any username or password directly in code.